# Word Styles lost when Word is restarted

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have had this problem for about a year.  When I restart Word, either because I lost power, or because Word crashed, or became non-responsive, my styles are lost because Word is unable to open the normal.dotm file.  If I have defined any styles, I have to redefine them.  I have learned to save a document that I call Style Master, and copy the styles from it to Normal, where they survive as long as I have Word open, but they are lost on restarting Word.

I am using Windows 10, on a 2017 desktop computer.  This doesn't happen with my 2021 laptop computer which is eligible for Windows 11.  I have tried reinstalling Office, and it doesn't solve the problem.

```
 -     -     Robert McClenon
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the question that should have been asked: how to **prevent** those editing issues.

1. For power loss, even [a small UPS](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=amazon%20uninterruptible%20power%20supply&i=electronics) can allow graceful shutdown. This also avoids damage to the drives.
2. Word crashed? That's unusual! MS *Word* is a mature product, which which should not crash, nor become unresponsive (unless the document is far too large for available RAM, in which case it uses the *far slower* [page file](https://computerinfobits.com/adjust-page-file-windows-10/)).

   To fix that issue, reinstall and update MS Word, if it crashes, or try another document editor, such as free LibreOffice Writer, which can open and save Word documents -- both current, and older versions no longer supported by Word itself.

   If it's unresponsive for *large* files, get more RAM, or use a faster PC. If you're in a corporate environment, explain to decision makers that frequent slowdown or crashes impacts work efficiency and can cause loss of a document.

Answer (score 0):

on the Developer tab, in the Templates group, click Document Template. In the Templates and Add-ins dialog, make sure "Automatically update document styles" is not checked.
[image]

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but what should I be editing or viewing that has a Developer tab in a Templates group, and then has a Templates and Add-ins dialog?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you.  You mention a poorly written Add-In.  How can I check what the Add-Ins are?  I get the feeling that I am a retired IT engineer asking stupid questions.

Comment: Hi, Robertmcclenon, "Poorly written add-in" is not my reply, it's Charles Kenyon's answer, and you should reply under his answer.

Answer (score 0):

### These styles are stored in your [Normal template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Normal): Normal.dotm. Something is interfering with you saving changes to that template.

It is likely a poorly written Add-In causing this. You would want to figure out the cause. However, you can use a workaround.

**Here is a macro to force the Normal template to save:**

```
Sub NormalTemplateSave()
    ' Charles Kenyon
    ' 16 March 2022
    ' Save the Normal Template
    Application.NormalTemplate.Saved = False
    Application.NormalTemplate.Save
End Sub
```

Just run the macro after you make any changes to styles.

Here are links to Word MVP advice on how to use macros you find in a forum.

- Greg Maxey's [Install/Employ vba procedures](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html)
- Graham Mayor's [Instructions for Installing Macros](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm)

Here is a link to [my article on the Microsoft site on backing up your Normal template](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/backup-normaldotm-template-using-a-macro/81aea1ae-e31b-437e-ac4a-3ebf9b4f7b5f). Here is the Windows version of that macro:

```
Sub NormalBackup()
 ' Run to Backup Normal template to dated backup
 ' Charles Kenyon 10 Jan 2020 
 '  https://www.addbalance.com/word/normal-backup.htm
 ' Appends date to "Normal Backup" when saving, saves in special folder, 
 '   then returns save path to current - thanks to Jay Freedman for that
 ' This code must be in the Normal template to work - not in another global

 '
 On Error Resume Next
 Dim strName As String
 Dim intLenPath As Integer ' length of path to templates folder without name of folder
 Dim strPath As String 'Holder for current path
 Dim strStorePath As String
 '
 Let intLenPath = InStrRev(Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdUserTemplatesPath), "\")
 Let strStorePath = Left(Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdUserTemplatesPath), intLenPath)
 Let strStorePath = strStorePath & "Normal Backups"
 '
 ' Check if folder exists, if not, create it
 If Dir(strStorePath) = vbNullString Then MkDir (strStorePath)
 '
 Let strPath = Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath)
 Let strName = "Normal Backup"
 ' add date & Time
 Let strName = strName & " " & Format((Year(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "20##") & "-" & _
    Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "0#") & "-" & _
    Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#") & "-" & _
    Format(Now(), "HH_mm") 'add date & time
 '
 ' Do the save
 ' MsgBox strStorePath & strName & ".dotm"
 ThisDocument.Save 'save normal template (code holder) itself
 ThisDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=strStorePath & "\" & strName & ".dotm", Addtorecentfiles:=False
 ' Reset save path
 Let Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath) = strPath
 '
 ' reset error message
 On Error GoTo -1
 End Sub
```

Here is a link to my Chapter on [Understanding Styles in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm).